# How do I remove square brackets and commas from ["000-000-0000-000","000-000-0000-000","000-000-0000-000"] in SQL redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

How do I remove square brackets and commas from  ["000-000-0000-000","000-000-0000-000","000-000-0000-000"] in sql amazonredshift

I tried ltrim it didn't work. It prompted me to use cast function. Not sure how should I use cast function here.

Comment: Use replace or the regular expression replace function

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-replace/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove square brackets and commas from the given string, REGEXP_REPLACE function can be used. Try this command;

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column_name, '[\[\],]', '', 'g') AS modified_column
FROM your_table_name;
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: It gave me the following error [42883] ERROR: function regexp_replace(super, "unknown", "unknown", "unknown") does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script.
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('[ "000-000-0000-000","000-000-0000-000","000-000-0000-000" ]', '[', ''), ']', '');